# How to make Chrome minimise when upper-right cross is clicked

Tags: google-chrome

I have enough CPU and RAM (and typically few enough tabs) that I'd like to have Chrome never close - so it opens faster.

I have found ways of doing this when then final tab is closed, but I haven't found a way to do this when the upper-right cross is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the cross is to close the program. If you want to affect its behaviour, you have to do that from the chrome source code if you have access to it. One thing you can since what you really want is 'chrome never close' You can:

1. Always run the program by default on startup
2. Run the chrome on background. **As you probably guessed from the name, a background Chrome app will keep running in the background, even after you close all the Chrome windows.** You can find out how to do that [here](https://pctonic.net/improve-chromes-startup-time-by-installing-a-background-app/)

Comment: Even with both those settings enabled, the webpages have to be reloaded when Chrome is reopened.